# How do I get the caller's file name and line number without passing them as parameters?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have three files `foo1`, `foo2`, and `foo3`.

`foo2` and `foo3` call a function in `foo1`.

I am trying to have foo1 detect the file name and line number of the caller without passing those as parameters in the function.

How can I do this?

Comment: I like the solution of making a macro to call it and pass it in without you having to pass `__FILE__` every time.

Comment: I know about doing that but curious on getting the filename and linenumber without having to rely on macro to hide the other two parameters

Comment: A debugger can show you that information, so a solution without macros will probably involve making your program act like a debugger on itself. I don't know how to make that happen, but step 1 is to decide which debugging libraries are available for your chosen platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a native program, the concept of files and lines doesn't hold ground any more. The program is just a stream of commands to the processor - the names of the functions, variables, the line numbers, the file names, all is lost during compilation.

Extracting debugging information from a program is virtually impossible. That program would have to be specifically compiled to have the debugging information attached. Sometimes (like the Visual C++), the debugging info is extracted into a separate file - but you would need that file and know its format, to extract that info. And you would be getting only the debug info. Not the compiled code.

The parameters are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

This is highly platform and compiler dependant, and can't generally be done. Your system *may* have extensions such as the GNU [`backtrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace) function.

Comment: So there is no practical/generic way to implement this?

Comment: @Tes_Gulliver - The practical way is to pass them as parameters to the function.

Comment: I know about passing them as parameters and using a macro to "hide" the parameters.  Was curious if you could do this without having to resort to either

Comment: @Tes_Gulliver, I wouldn't call it resorting. I consider eliminating the repetitiveness of passing that information in so you can get a detailed error message one of the legitimate uses of macros.

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part.  Then let me ask this, is there any specific jni functions to get a filename and linenumber or does it have to be passed as a parameter/create a macro that does this some how?